# Add Pin using Coordinates

Tags: ios, mapkit

I am creating a map app, and I am using the built-in forward geocoder. So far, everything is working great. When I enter an address, the geocoder converts the results beautifully into coordinates, displayed in the console with NSLog. How do I now convert these coordinates into a pin that is displayed on the map? Here is my code.

```
[self.geocoder geocodeAddressString:address completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if ([placemarks count] > 0)
        {
            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            CLLocation *location = placemark.location;
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;

           NSLog (@"%f %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude);

        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use an `MKPointAnnotation`

```
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
[annotation setCoordinate:myCoordinate];
[annotation setTitle:@"My Place"];
[[self mapView] addAnnotation:annotation];
```

Comment: This works great. But my SearchBar keyboard won't disappear, and I would like the map to zoom to the location... how can I do this?